# Close modal from the parent component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, eventemitter

So I've got this parent component, let's call it List, which has property `addModal: boolean;` and a

```
<button 
    (click)="addModal = true">
    Show Modal
</button>
```

in the template, which shows the modal component normally on click, which looks like this:

```
<app-modal *ngIf="addModal"></app-modal>
```

The `app-modal` is a separate component, and I would like to be able to close the modal from within it. As I'm learning Angular, I understood that it can be done with the `EventEmitter`. I got stuck at this point, this is what I've got now, but can't figure out how to listen for that close event... This is how the Modal component looks like:

```
@Output() addModal = new EventEmitter();

decline() {
   this.addModal.emit(true);  //?  console logs the EventEmitter object
}
```

in the Modal template:

```
<button (click)="decline()"></button>
```

I know that I should catch that in the parent component, but can't figure it out exactly...

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen for emitted events on the host element where `$event` is the emitted value, in your case `true`:

```
<app-modal *ngIf="addModal" (addModal)="doSomething($event)"></app-modal>
```

As a general tip, the name `addModal` is not really a good name because it doesn't explain the event. Consider changing it to something like `declined` instead.

Comment: I see, thanks. I've noticed that it works also without the $event argument, i just set the addModal to false inside the doSomething

Comment: @Smithy Yes it works without, you only need to pass it as an argument to the callback function if you actually need it. If not you can just leave it out.